# How to prgramly fire a key event to my app only?

Tags: java, keyevent, awtrobot

I have a Java program that has many components with their key handlers. I want to frequently fire some key events to my app only so that the focused component will trigger its key handler. The Robot class just fire the key event to the current focused windows, not my app. I want to fire the key in my app only, event when it lost focus.

Can you give me a sight? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to create a simulated key press? Often, your key press handler should call a method of some kind in some sort of domain logic layer or MVC Controller without doing much of logic on itself. Even if it doesn't, you can refactor it to do so. This way, you can call that method from your timer without simulating key presses.

Comment: Yes, It is necessary. If just call the handler method, there are no problem.